Why does the QFT provide for so many controlled rotations?
I'm new to quantum and I wanted to understand why QFT uses controlled rotation gates. Thank you all

I suggest reading the book QIQC by Nielsen and Chuang. An entire chapter explains how to build a QFT circuit and why the rotation gates are needed.
In short, the main idea is to build a circuit that performs the following transformation:
$$|j\rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} e^{2\pi ijk/N}|k\rangle.$$
The reason why the QFT circuit uses a series of controlled rotation gates $R_k$ is to build the Fourier-transformed state incrementally. Each controlled rotation gate $R_k$ contributes a progressively smaller phase rotation depending on the basis state $|k\rangle$ (see Wikipedia for the definition of $R_k$ and QFT circuit diagram).
